# How to connect to database and get custom data in Phorum?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the external authentication system. Therefore, there are a lot of user data, which is not available in Phorum.

I am using the last post module, although I want to get the information from the last post user, from my own user table (I have some data, like avatar, birth info etc). I want to show in my Phorum. How can I achieve this?

I've tried to simply connect via a: `mysql_query();` but then I just get `No database selected error.`

I've searched for hours - I cannot find any documentation regarding getting custom data from your own user table.

Comment: Aside: there's been much discussion around the use of using tags in question titles, and the community decided that [it prefers titles to be written as a question instead, without tag devices](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190). I've amended your post, if you could use that format in future it'll save on edit work - thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend using mysqli, as mysql is deprecated. First make sure that your connection is correct. No database selected means you probably do not have your connection included at the top.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Make sure that your sql statement looks like so (Notice the `$con` in the `mysqli_query()`):

```
$sql = "select * from TableName";
if ($que = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    // Query has ran
}
```